# Having trouble splitting a string

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm scraping some data from Google Translate like so:

```
import urllib
import mechanize

get_url=("https://translate.google.ie/translate_a/single?client=t&sl=auto&tl=es&hl=en&dt=bd&dt=ex&dt=ld&dt=md&dt=qca&dt=rw&dt=rm&dt=ss&dt=t&dt=at&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&source=btn&ssel=0&tsel=3&kc=0&tk=520887|911740&q=Hellow%20World")

browser=mechanize.Browser()
browser.set_handle_robots(False)
browser.addheaders=[('User-agent','Chrome')]

translate_text=urllib.urlopen(get_url).read()
print translate_text
```

Which gives me the following output:

```
[["Hellow Mundial", "Hellow World"]]
undefined
"en"
undefined
undefined
[["Hellow", 1,…], ["World", 2,…]]
0.022165652
undefined
[["en"], undefined, [0.022165652]]
```

Which can be seen here:

[image]

So I try to split the data on the ]] so my output will only be:

```
[["Hellow Mundial", "Hellow World"]]
```

I'm splitting the data like so:

```
translate_text=translate_text.split("]]")
print translate_text[0]
```

However, when I run this I get the page markup. Before the split, I got the query result. How come the split is causing this and not splitting the string as intended?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google is returning something similar to`JSON` format (but not actually JSON) for you which can be very easily parsed after a simple RegEx to replace any consecutive commas with a single one:

Try:

```
import json
import re

# replace any consecutive commas with a single one
translate_text = re.sub( ',+', ',', translate_text ).strip()
arr = json.loads(translate_text)
print arr[0][0][0] # prints "Hellow Mundial"
print arr[0][0][1] # prints "Hellow World"
```

Note that `translate_text` is a string, and `arr` is a Python array. `json.loads` was able to parse into a native Python format for you so that you could use simple List and Dictionary look-ups.

Comment: I'll look into the JSON library, cheers. I'm trying to follow this tutorial and he didn't seem to use it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Igvf5C7qwO0. Specific question is 11:50.

Comment: Ouch - if he's actually splitting it manually, that's incredibly wrong. The whole point of JSON is to make it *very* easy to send arrays and dictionaries between machines.

Comment: That is not valid json being returned

Comment: @MartinKonecny Great, thanks for letting me know. I'll look into the Json library. Nothing worse than following a tutorial to find out that it's wrong or a hacky solution.

Comment: @joemartin, that is not json so you are going to have a hard time parsing it as json

Comment: @PadraicCunningham What solution would you suggest?

Comment: @joemartin, what are you trying to extract?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham My input - "Hello World" and the output "Hola Mundial".. I spelled Hello as Hellow but you can see what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham - hmmm I did a double check and looks like I'm incorrect. It would be valid JSON if it weren't for the `undefined` entries.

Comment: @MartinKonecny,  it is almost json but there are a few nice errors throw in there , I have no idea what format it is supposed to actually be but I think it might be a case for regex

Comment: Ok updated my answer to convert the feed from Google into json that is parseable.

Comment: Might as well get the first list with the regex though if that is all the OP wants. Not sure I would trust the output enough to use json

Answer (score 0):

Those `]]` you see are not a part of the actual string. they are placed there by Python to indicate that the stuff inside the `[]` and delimited by `,` are elements of an array.

In your case, the first element of the array is a 2D array whose first dimension only contains one element. That element is itself an array containing two strings.

If I understand your question correctly, you don't need to split anything at all. Try simply typing:

```
print translate_text[0]
```

without the split.

Answer (score 0):

I think the string you want to use is in JSON format, I suggest you to parse it with [`json`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) lib:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.loads('[["Hellow Mundial", "Hellow World"]]')
[[u'Hellow Mundial', u'Hellow World']]
```

The JSON will be translated into Python objects (currently here list of list):

```
>>> l = json.loads('[["Hellow Mundial", "Hellow World"]]')
>>> l[0]
["Hellow Mundial", "Hellow World"]
>>> l[0][0]
"Hellow Mundial"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could extract the first list with a regex:

```
get_url=("https://translate.google.ie/translate_a/single?client=t&sl=auto&tl=es&hl=en&dt=bd&dt=ex&dt=ld&dt=md&dt=qca&dt=rw&dt=rm&dt=ss&dt=t&dt=at&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&source=btn&ssel=0&tsel=3&kc=0&tk=520887|911740&q=Hellow%20World")

import requests
r = requests.get(get_url)

import re

print(re.search("\[(\"(.*?)\")\]",r.content).group(1))

"Hello World como estas","Hello World how are you"
```

If you want the names in variables:

```
a ,b  = re.search("\[(\"(.*?)\")\]",r.text).group(1).split(",")
print(a,b)
"Hello World como estas" "Hello World how are you"
```

If you really want a list you can use ast.literal_eval after getting the first list with re:

```
import re
from ast import literal_eval
print(literal_eval(re.search("\[(\"(.*?)\")\]",r.text).group(0)))
['Hello World como estas', 'Hello World how are you']
```

If you run the code in your browser  it actually downloads as a .txt file.